# Script to delete specific files from all zip archives in a directory

Tags: file, scripting, zip

I'd like to delete the file with a name, say file.xml, from all zip archives in a given directory. Any simple solution is welcome, whether it's a bash script, python code or whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it recursively in a dir

```
#!/bin/bash
find /my/dir -name "*.zip" -exec zip \{\}  -d file.xml \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
find /starting/folder -name "*.zip"|xargs -I{} zip -d {} file.xml
```

Do make a backup of your zips before...